# How to allow a machine to only read from a specific branch via Gitlab?

Tags: git, composer-php, repository, gitlab

I have an application which relies on other modules to work properly. Those modules are on my Gitlab server. These are pulled via `composer.json` to the client's server. How the client gets the permission to do so is via "Deployment keys". I take the client's public key and add it to the module's deployment keys section in the settings.

The problem with this approach is that the client can open `composer.json` and simply pull any branch they desire as long as they know the branch name. However, I'd like for the client to be able to pull only **one** specific branch. So when I setup the client's server, I know for certain that they can only get what I want them to and not the whole repository.

Is there a way to set Gitlab in such a way to only allow access to a certain branch and not the whole repository?

The Gitlab version is 9.

Please note that this is all about deployment and not to help some development process. Allowing forking etc. doesn't really apply to my situation.

Comment: In short: no. You can write-, merge-, fork- or delete-protect branches, but cannot read-protect.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I don't believe that it is a true duplicate of the one you linked to, since my situation is totally different.

Anyway, is there a workaround I could use which might not even involve Gitlab at all?

Comment: You can try gitolite with [deny-rules](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf-2/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restrict access to master branch on git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38864405/how-to-restrict-access-to-master-branch-on-git)

Comment: @1615903 The answers there list every possible kind of protection except the only one the OP needs — read protection! :-D