# Bitbucket allow tags on master but other changes via PR

Tags: git, bitbucket

Using GitHub flow, is there a way with Bitbucket (permissions or hooks) to prevent pushes to `master` (PRs only) but allow tags for releases?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restrict access to master branch on git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38864405/how-to-restrict-access-to-master-branch-on-git)

Comment: Thanks, no, that only describes adding a branch setting on master that prevents any changes except via PR. This is useful, but it then prevents doing a push to master of tags when doing a release.

Comment: It should not prevent pushing tags. If it does, configure that it shouldn't.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "tag on master". A tag either exists—and therefore names a Git object—or does not exist. The object that a tag names can be any of Git's four internal object types. If the object type is *annotated tag* the tag is itself an annotated tag and Git will usually follow the annotated tag object to the next object, and keep following until Git arrives at some non-tag-object. Usually that's a specific *commit* and hence the ultimate target of the tag is any arbitrary commit. There is no such thing as a protected commit, so you can tag any commit.

Comment: To *push* a tag (with `git push`) you simply run `git push <tagname>`. If the tag name is ambiguous—e.g., if you create `refs/tags/master` while you have `refs/heads/master` (the *branch* named `master`) as well—you may have to be more explicit about the reference namespace, but you should avoid creating ambiguous names in the first place as they confuse humans. (Git has rules to disambiguate, so Git itself does not get confused, but Git's rules are confusing to humans.)

Comment: Thanks, with the 'master' branch permission in Bitbucket set to prevent 'Changes without a pull request', it stops a push being allowed to master which contains an annotated tag (vx.x.x), which is designed to kick off a deployment to production. I suppose the question then - is there any way of only allowing PRs to master or pushes that contain a v annotated tag (or just any annotated tag). For example with a Bitbucket hook? How are people doing GitHub flow with Bitbucket?