# Using Jenkins stored credentials in Pipeline as yml for git push

Tags: git, jenkins, yaml, jenkins-pipeline

I am writing a Pipeline in Jenkins where I need to push the changes back to BitBucket using script. I have used stored credentials to get the code from BitBucket but unable to push it back to the server. Here is my script:

```
  - stage: Pull Code and Merge master in UAT
  steps:
    script:
      - "git credentialsId: '0b69d4a0-623b-4ba6-8e2c-8419ced4a31a', url: 'repo url'"
      - sh 'git status'
      - sh 'git checkout release/uat'
      - sh 'git merge -m "merging changes from main to UAT" origin/master'
      - "git push credentialsId: '0b69d4a0-623b-4ba6-8e2c-8419ced4a31a',url: 'repo url"  
      - sh 'git status'
```

git push is causing the errors. I don't know a way to do push using stored credentials

I am using [this plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-as-yaml-plugin/blob/master/src/test/resources/post/postSteps.yml) to run pipeline as yaml.

Here is the error being thrown:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 14: expecting '}', found ':' @ line 14, column 33.
         git push credentialsId: '0b69d4a0-623b-4ba6-8e2c-8419ced4a31a',url: 'http://10.0.110.4:7990/scm/ceye/ceye-admin.git
                               ^

1 error

at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:150)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:120)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:132)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.addError(SourceUnit.java:350)
at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:144)
at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:110)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:234)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:168)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:943)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:605)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:571)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:523)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:337)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
```

Finished: FAILURE

Comment: I don't know BitBucket, but had a similar problem with Gitlab. In my case the master branch was protected. Meaning only 'Maintainers' were allowed to make changes to the master branch. Maybe something like this is your problem too. Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38864405/how-to-restrict-access-to-master-branch-on-git

Comment: @frank i am the admin of the repo. There is a problem in the syntax of git push.If you could have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

The `git` command of Jenkins is basically just a wrapper of `git clone/pull`, it has no `push` option. The syntax error is caused because Jenkins expects the name of a parameter but gets "push".

To make this work you could either use a ssh key or encode the username and password in the url, like so:

```
sh "git push https://${username}:${password}@github.com/...repo.../.com
```

If the password is not URL save (contains `&` etc), you have to escape it first.

Comment: how do I add ${username} and password as variable?

Comment: can you use the withCredentials environment in your yaml setup?

Comment: yeah. I can use that

Comment: withCredentials generates those two variables for you (given a credentialsId), you can specify how the variables should be called or it uses some defaults

Comment: see here for more information: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/