# Branch master is read only and can be modified using pull requests only in Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am having a repo on Bitbucket and it contains code for  **Drools**. I am having different branches and trying to merge a branch into the master branch. But it ends up with the following error
[image]
I create a pull request and can not merge it. It gives the following error:
[image]
I am unable to understand the cause for it. As I am having admin permissions for the repo.
Here are the permissions on my side.

[image]

Permissions for me in the repo.
[image]
Any ideas about what's wrong with it? Thanks a lot. I am not finding any reason behind the error being the admin of the repo

Comment: Who is listed in the exemptions? The screenshot is cut off and we can't see that

Comment: @evolutionxbox Sorry. which screenshot are you talking about?

Comment: @evolutionxbox are you talking about the one that indicates the error with the merge button? I just updated it.

Comment: In the screenshot with the branch permissions, the preventions are highlighted, but we can't see who is exempt.

Comment: Have you tried merging via the webui?

Comment: @Tschösi yeah I tried it but can not do that

Comment: @evolutionxbox just updated exemptions screenshot

Comment: @Jamshaid I can see that no exemptions. Maybe add yourself or admins as an exemption to the rule? Otherwise it doesn't matter if you're an admin or not

Comment: Okay. I'll try that

Comment: @evolutionxbox I added exemption and it worked. Thanks

Comment: similar question with a lot of information [How to restrict access to master branch on git(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38864405/how-to-restrict-access-to-master-branch-on-git)